# How to htaccess redirect somthing/anything to somethingnew/anything

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect URLs like below pattern

www.mydomain.com/about/anything => www.mydomain.com/aboutme/anything
(anything part should be same in both URL)

I've tried below rules but didn't work fine

```
 RewriteRule ^/about(/?)?$ http://www.mydomain.com/aboutme/$1 [R=300, L]
```

and

```
 RewriteRule ^/about([^/]*)?$ http://www.mydomain.com/aboutme/$1 [R=300, L]
```

Any help
Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using `.htaccess`, you wouldn't try to match a preceding `/`. Using `mod_rewrite` like your example shows you should be able to use this:

```
RewriteRule ^about/(.*)$ aboutme/$1 [R,L]
```

If you want it to be permanent you would change the flag to `[R=301,L]`.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a 301 redirect for this.

```
Redirect 301 /about/ http://www.mydomain.com/aboutme/
```

Comment: Thanks but I want do do this using `RewriteRule`

Comment: you may still want to consider a 301 redirect for SEO purposes.